# При установке принтера hp p1102 заодно устанавливается драйвера принтера hp 1100? Почему? Это нормально?

Tags: windows-10

При установке принтера hp p1102 заодно устанавливается драйвера принтера hp 1100? Почему? Это нормально?
Также принтер периодически уходит в спячку и просыпается только с кнопки включения, как это исправить?

[image: Принтера]

Comment: *Это нормально?* Нет. Серия 1100 и серия P1100 не то что не одно и то же - вообще рядом не лежали.

Comment: так устанавливается когда ставишь оригинальные драйвера с сайта. Появляется сразу 2 почему то.

Comment: *так устанавливается когда ставишь оригинальные драйвера с сайта.* Вот эти: https://support.hp.com/ru-ru/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-p1100-printer-series/4110394/model/4110303 ? Попробуйте поставить с Windows Update. Для чего надо удалить устройство  в диспетчере оборудования (если при удалении устройства будут предложения удалить дрова - соглашаться), удалить установленные НР дрова, отключить принтер, перегрузиться, подключить принтер, если он не подхватится - разрешить поиск обновлённых дров в Update, а если подхватится - смотреть, чьи дрова встали (если не майкрософт - повторить).